# Can't explain this Node clustering behavior

Tags: node.js, libuv

I'm learning about threads and how they interact with Node's native cluster module. I saw some behavior I can't explain that I'd like some help understanding.

My code:

```
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 1;
const cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  cluster.fork();
} else {
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
      res.send('Hi there');
    });
  });

  app.listen(3000);
}
```

I benchmarked this code with one request using apache benchmark.

`ab -c 1 -n 1 localhost:3000/` yielded these connection times

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:   605  605   0.0    605     605
Waiting:      605  605   0.0    605     605
Total:        605  605   0.0    605     605
```

So far so good. I then ran `ab -c 2 -n 2 localhost:3000/` (doubling the number of calls from the benchmark). I expected the total time to double since I limited the libuv thread pool to one thread per child process and I only started one child process. But nothing really changed. Here's those results.

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       0
Processing:   608  610   3.2    612     612
Waiting:      607  610   3.2    612     612
Total:        608  610   3.3    612     612
```

For extra info, when I further increase the number of calls with `ab -c 3 -n 3 localhost:3000/`, I start to see a slow down.

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:   599  814 352.5    922    1221
Waiting:      599  814 352.5    922    1221
Total:        599  815 352.5    922    1221
```

I'm running all this on a quadcore mac using Node v14.13.1.

---

**tldr**: how did my benchmark not use up all my threads? I forked one child process with one thread in its libuv pool - so the one call in my benchmark should have been all it could handle without taking longer. And yet the second test (the one that doubled the amount of calls) took the same amount of time as the benchmark.

Comment: Presumably, your first benchmark wasn't fully saturating the threads that nodejs had so there was room to process more in your 2nd.  Then finally with the 3rd benchmark, you hit the limit and thus see a slow-down.

Comment: I do hope you realize that in practice, you wouldn't add clustering for asynchronous crypto operations since they are processed in a libuv threadpool already and are non-blocking for the main thread.  If you had a lot of these crypto operations, you may increase the libuv thread pool size at least up to the number of CPU cores you have.

Comment: I'm just using that crypto function to simulate doing work that takes time.

The first line of my code `process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 1;` is meant to limit the thread pool to just 1. So I think the first benchmark should have saturated the threads.

Comment: When you double the load and it doesn't take more time, then apparently you weren't saturating the CPU.  Not much more I can say than that.